# Include both #ifdef and #else code in doxygen output

Tags: doxygen

If have code in the following format:

```
#ifdef MY_DEFINE
    ///some doxy comment
#else
    ///other doxy comment
#endif
```

MY_DEFINE is defined at compile time. My issue is that when doxy processes the code above, only "other doxy comment" is handled. Defining MY_DEFINE in the doxyfile makes it so "some doxy comment" is handled. I need both doxy comments to make it into the doxygen output.

Is there a simple catch all configuration I can add to the doxyfile?

The doxygen generation needs to be run on different machines, so something not needing additional installation is preferred. There are other #define statements which need to be handled by doxygen, so setting ENABLE_PREPROCESSING to NO is not enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? When I set `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING=NO` and the comment is above a function I see both comments.

Comment: Agree, but other #define statements are not processed by doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING=YES`, then add a predefined symbol `PREDEFINED=DOXYGEN`

Then you can:

```
#if defined(MY_DEFINE) || defined(DOXYGEN)
/// if defined
#endif

#if !defined(MY_DEFINE) || defined(DOXYGEN)
/// if not defined
#endif
```

The drawback is that you cannot use `#else`. Also Doxygen gets confused if the same symbol is defined to be two different things on different preprocessor settings.

If you disable `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` you cannot document `#define`'s in your headers.